# Can a majority of DC electronics run on high current (i.e. lamp, car) batteries directly?

Tags: power-supply, batteries

I've seen some people run an inverter off a large set of batteries, to power mobile devices and whatnot or even game consoles. My thoughts are, if I can rig some lamp batteries together and use a portable tv I could power something such as an SNES (super nintendo/famicom).

The SNES would require 12V (suitable for some larger batteries, or some in series) and ~200mA possibly less when running. Would it be a good idea to plug a battery directly in to where the DC socket is, sans the regulation and all that? Does the adapter provide some sort of expected power or behavior different from a "pure" DC source?

Also a silly question, assuming I've a pile of 6V lamp batteries that could supply 100mA each - would I be able to place them in series+parallel to achieve 12V + higher maximum current draw for this purpose?

Comment: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/790/142 http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/16422/142

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you can run it safely off batteries depends on the design of the unit.

- If the regulator is in the supply then you will need to add a regulator to your batteries.
- If the regulator is in the unit you will be able to directly attach your batteries.

Most systems have the regulator in the unit, so it *should* be OK to just power it off battery.

Be warned though that "12V" lead acid car batteries are actually a higher voltage (around 13.5V) so a regulator should really be used with these for safety.

As for increasing current - yes, just put pairs of 6V batteries in parallel.

Connecting batteries in parallel increases the current.  Connecting them in series increases the voltage.

If you think of a 12V battery as two 6V batteries in series, then connect these "12v batteries" in parallel you will get 12V and higher current.

Electrically, a single 12V battery is the same as 2 6V batteries in series.  A battery is made up of cells.  Each cell can provide between 1.2V and 1.5V depending on chemistry.  A 6V battery is a *battery* of 4 cells (battery in the non-electrical sense - think artillery battery, a group of artillery guns) - 4 x 1.5 is 6V.  Put two 6V batteries together and you get a 8 cells in series - that's 8 x 1.5V = 12V.

Comment: Glad it could be straightforward, will test on less precious consoles first. :)