# Is connecting a 2 A adapter to a 1.3 A electrical device safe?

Tags: safety

Is connecting a higher-amp (e.g. 2 A) adapter to a lower-amp (e.g. 1.3 A) electrical device safe?

I wonder if it will cause the adapter to over heat and cause fire or cause damage to the electrical device.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does using a electrical device that is connecting to a series of power extension safe?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34035/does-using-a-electrical-device-that-is-connecting-to-a-series-of-power-extension)

Comment: I already voted to close, but I think this is a better question to be a duplicate of: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16422/limiting-current-from-a-5v-power-supply

Comment: @Kellenjb, don't know why, but your comment is hilarious :)

Answer (score 3):

No it won't overheat the adapter. That's designed to deliver **up to** 2 A, and everything less than that is safe. If you disconnect the device the current will be zero, and that's also safe. The adapter will supply the **required** current, not the current it **can** supply.

Never do the inverse: connecting a 2 A device to a 1.3 A adapter, though.